# Find & replace on a folder of .txt (but only first 1-3 lines)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grep, kubuntu, find-and-replace

I have a folder of .txt files. They all look like this:

```
Title: Title of blog post.
Tags: tag1,tag2,tag3

Text on the post. Just my thoughts. 

> A blockqoute

Written in *markdown.* Using <http://scriptogr.am/>

Nothing really scary.
```

Lets say I want to change the name of **tag1** to **tagOne** for some reason. Is it possible to run some sort of *grep* or *find & replace* on these txt inside my folder?

Bonus if I can perform the find&replace only the first 1-3 lines, since I may write the word "tag1" in the body of my blog post, but dont wish to change it there.

I'm on windows 7. But have access to a Kubuntu machine (if that would make any difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is on your GNU/Linux machine using [`sed(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed). Assuming that only the text files you want to transform are on the directory:

```
$ for a in /path/to/directory/*txt; do sed -i '1,3{s/tag1/tagOne/g;}' "${a}"; done
```

What this does, explained in more detail:

- There is a loop to iterate over the files you want to work with:

  ```
  for a in [...]; do [...]; done
  ```
- For each iteration, the variable `a` will hold the name of a file matching the globbing pattern `/path/to/directory/*txt`.
- Once we know what file are we working with, let's `do` something with it, in this case, a `sed` command:

  ```
  sed -i '1,3{s/tag1/tagOne/g;}'
  ```
- The `-i` flag means `in place`, so the `sed` command won't need to write temporary files. Next, `1,3` defines the range of lines the `sed` command will operate on. The curly braces are the grouping operator, meaning "from line 1 to 3, execute the inner command". That command is `s`: replace. The replace command accepts a regular expression to match against, and a string to replace that match with, in this case, you want to replace `tag1` with `tagOne`. The command ends with the `g` modifier, which means `global`.

In plain English, the whole command reads:

> For every file in the designated directory, whose name ends with txt, replace in it, but only in the lines one to three, all the occurrences of tag1 with tagOne.

Comment: Can I do it on my mac?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
for k in *.txt
do
  ex -sc '1s/tag1/tagOne/3|x' "$k"
done
```

1. `1` move to first line
2. `3` select 3 lines
3. `s` substitute
4. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in notepad++ when you hit

```
ctrl+shift+F
```

command is called Find in files.

It does not accomplish the "first three lines". A workaround for that may be to name my tags @tag1 or #tag1 or &tag1 to begin with.